# how to cancel review of the google assistant app from "Actions on Google"

Tags: actions-on-google

I have submitted an app for review but I have to change the Targeting Locations of the app. When I resubmitted, it said can't send 2 versions of same app cancel the first review. How do I cancel it?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can. You may have to wait for the first review to conclude before submitting again.

Answer (score 1):

You can withdraw the submission of your app. In the bottom of the overview page for your app, there is the UI for the review status of your app. If your app is under reviewing, there is the "Withdraw" button on the row of the submission. You can cancel your submission bu clicking the "Withdraw" button.

See: https://console.actions.google.com/project/hitandblow-4e1bd/overview

And, you need to withdraw the current submission first, before re-submitting the new version.